# .net 4.0 threadpool exception

Tags: c#, exception, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

the below code throw below exception when compiled with .net 4.0 ，while complied with .net 2.0, it's ok, any guy encounter with me?, please kindly help(I didn't use DateTime in the callback function)。

```
public void ProcessPriceUpdate()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref this.counts);

    lock (contractLock)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(priceCallback, null);
    }
}


>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>Message=Value to add was out of range.
>Parameter name: value
>Source=mscorlib
>ParamName=value
>StackTrace:
>at System.DateTime.Add(Double value, Int32 scale)
>at System.Threading.PlatformHelper.get_ProcessorCount()
>at System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinOnce()
>at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.QueueSegment.TryDequeue(IThreadPoolWorkItem& node)
>at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dequeue(ThreadPoolWorkQueueThreadLocals tl, IThreadPoolWorkItem& callback, Boolean& missedSteal)
>at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you please post call back method also with more descriptive info

Comment: Your trace starts from `PerformWaitCallback()`? Can you show how do you define `priceCallback`? Try creating new instance of WaitCallback using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(priceCallback), null);`

Comment: Is it the year 10,000 yet?  I wasn't paying attention.  That or the clock on this machine is badly messed up.  It is trying to add 30 seconds to the last value returned by DateTime.UtcNow